# OAuth and user change of password

Tags: docusignapi

With this workflow:

1. We are an integrator with no users of our own. Our clients will each
   have their own DocuSign account with their own users.
2. We'll send envelopes for them and they'll authenticate using OAuth in our
   application. We'll store the tokens, etc. for future
   authentication/authorization.
3. User goes to the DocuSign website and changes their password.

Will that invalidate the OAuth token? If so, what is the best way to determine that the token is now invalid and that we need to get a new one for the user?

Answer (score 0):

The oAuth token will still be valid even when the user changes their DocuSign password.

However the user can explicitly revoke the access to your app through Docusign if they want to.